Swift: Fast way to increment part of an integer array
I have an array of increasing integers like so: [0, 5, 23, …]. The array is big (> 500T). I have to find all elements larger than an input value x and add 1 to each of them.
I do the following:
extension Array where Element == Int {
    func incrementElements(largerThan x: Int) -> [Int] {
        return self.map { $0 > x ? $0 + 1 : $0 }
    }
}

So far so good. The problem is that this operation must be very fast and mine is too slow. Is there a faster way to do this?

…500 trillion elements?

Are you meant to increment/mutate the array in-place? You do know that .map creates a shallow-copy of the input array too?

You are testing every single element in the array ("is this element larger than x? okay, is this element larger than x? Okay, what about this element...?"). That's silly. If the array is sorted to begin with ("an array of increasing integers"), you already know that you only need to increment the elements after the last "smaller than or equal to x" element.
Thus it is necessary to traverse the array at most once, and it is only necessary to do any testing long enough to find the first element that is greater than x.
We can traverse the array most efficiently by pointing directly into its contiguous buffer storage. So our traversal might look like this:
// initial conditions
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] // or whatever
let k = 3 // or whatever; this is your `x`

// okay, here we go
array.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { buffer in
    var index: Int?
    for i in (buffer.startIndex..<buffer.endIndex) {
        if buffer[i] > k {
            index = i
            break
        }
    }
    if let index {
        for i in (index..<buffer.endIndex) {
            buffer[i] += 1
        }
    }
}

We could make this even faster by eliminating the first part of the traversal; instead, we could use a binary search to locate the first element that is greater than x. But this is left as an exercise for the reader.

You can implement that "traversal" part with zip(array.indices, array).first { index, element in element > k }?.index. swift-algorithms has partitioningIndex(where:) for binary search, so then you could plop that in to replace first(where:)

Could you elaborate on the benefit of using the underlying buffer in this case? Is it to prevent some CoW copy or something?

First, the function name is wrong. It’s the name that you would use for a function that modified the array in place. You return a new array, so you would write say
let newarray = oldarray.byIncrementingElementsGreaterThan(200)

Second, there is no way that you can buy any computer for any money that will handle two 500 terabyte arrays.
Third, you should post what problem you want to solve. Not how you think you would solve it.

"Second, there is no way that you can buy any computer for any money that will handle two 500 terabyte arrays." - Memory-mapped files to a huge SAN tho...
